# How to create a link outside of the jail, but accessable within the jail?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, chroot

I have created a chroot jail, but now I want to be able to create a link within the jail which links outside of the jail. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only method I can think of is used of a bind mount. A quick google found http://docs.1h.com/Bind_mounts

Comment: This is, pretty much the only way to do it, and it's how openvz does it.

Comment: Yes, indeed: `mount --bind /old /new`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as Christopher said, a bind mount will work.
But I think it will work only with directories and not at file level.

If you need file links you can use hard links but it will only work within a Linux ext filesystem (don't know if other fs support it)

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link) for a description of the difference between hard and soft links.